# Digital Signature Verification Errors

Tags: python, digital-signature

I am encrypting elements of a list, creating digital signatures and verifying that the list was sent by me. However, I am getting an error when trying to verify. Here is my code. Please help

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.Signature import pkcs1_15
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256

###################### A Decryption Algorithm ##########################
def decrypt (counterPriv, encryptedVote, decrypt):
 length = len(encryptedVote)

 for index in range(length):
     cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(counterPriv)
     plaintext = cipher.decrypt(encryptedVote[index])
     decrypt.append(plaintext)
 

######################################################################


############### My Personal Digital Signature Function ##############

def sign (privateKey, dataList, emptySig, hashList):
 dataLength = len(dataList)

 for index in range(dataLength):
     h = SHA256.new()
     h.update(dataList[index])
     signature = pkcs1_15.new(privateKey).sign(h)
     emptySig.append(signature)
     hashList.append(h)

############################################################################

authen_key = RSA.generate(1024, e=65537)
authen_priv_key = authen_key.exportKey("PEM")
authen_public_key = authen_key.publickey().exportKey("PEM")

counter_key = RSA.generate(1024, e=65537)
counter_priv_key = counter_key.exportKey("PEM")
counter_public_key = counter_key.publickey().exportKey("PEM")

decrypt2 = []
myAnswer = ['Bob', 'Dylan', '12345']
myAnswerEncrypted = []

counterPublicKey = RSA.importKey(counter_public_key)

for index in range(3):
    cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(counterPublicKey)
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(myAnswer[index].encode("utf-8"))
    myAnswerEncrypted.append(ciphertext)

decrypt(RSA.importKey(counter_priv_key), myAnswerEncrypted, decrypt2)

hashList = []
Signature_List = []
sign(RSA.importKey(authen_priv_key), decrypt2, Signature_List, hashList)

for index in range(len(hashList)):
    try:
        pkcs1_15.new(authen_key.publickey()).verify(hashList[index], 
         Signature_List[index])
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
```

I am having trouble with the .verify() function. The computer output tells me that "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'n'"

Comment: `authen_public_key` is the serialized form of the public key, suitable for saving and sharing with others. The argument that `.verify()` is expecting is a python object of the appropriate type, for example `authen_key.publickey()` should work.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks. It works! I will make the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two Crypto modules. The pycrypto and the pycryptodome. I try and your code work with the two modules.

With pycrypto I need to rename pkcs1_15 with PKCS1_v1_5:

```
from Crypto.Signature import PKCS1_v1_5 as pkcs1_15
```

However, I believe you are with conflict with the two modules and I will explain why.

In the pycrypto module, the `pkcs1_15.new(privateKey).sign(h)` returns a `byte` object and with the pycryptodome returns a `string` object. In this way, maybe you has using a merged import. Try run in a clear enviroment.

Comment: Ginklings I changed the import part of my code but I still get the error message: AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'n'

Comment: How are you running this?? Because I run it and it works. Try reinstall python or (better) use a dedicated e environ (with virtual env or conda)

Comment: Glinkings I am using Spyder